# Oracle cloud data warehouse

Tags: cloud, analytics, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

Is there any Oracle cloud data warehouse equivalent to Amazon Redshift and Google Big query? I came across Oracle 12c, Exadata, Autonomous Data warehouse which is coming soon. Not sure of the oracle product in cloud data warehousing

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has their managed version of Cassandra, Oracle Data Hub, out now [see the product page here](https://cloud.oracle.com/en_US/datahub).

They also have a [managed Hadoop distribution](https://cloud.oracle.com/en_US/big-data-cloud) that comes with `spark` and `Hive`. You can install `Hbase` on here, although I'm not sure that's officially supported.

The Autonomous Data Warehouse is meant to be a data warehouse and Oracle has dubbed it their "redshift killer"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Oracle Autonomous Data Warehouse (ADW) is an equivalent service from Oracle.
It is considered to have a super set of functionality , better performance and concurrency than Redshift  at very similar pricing.